# "Could Not load file or assembly" azure web appl

Tags: c#, mysql, azure-web-app-service

Hello i am getting this error when i run the system online and try to interact with my mysql database, the system works fine locally.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.9.5.0,        
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its 
  dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I understand this question is a duplicate, but i am doing all my development on a university computer so i cannot make changes to the GAC as far as i know.

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that any assembly that you used is deployed to your `bin` folder. Generally, the GAC is less and less used and `bin` is where dependencies are.